# Qt - How to set text on top of QLabel Image

Tags: qt, mobile, qt4, nokia

I believe QPainter is used, but I can't figure out how to combine the two.

```
QLabel* imageLabel = new QLabel();
QImage image("c://image.png");
imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
imageLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

QPainter* painter = new QPainter();
painter->setPen(Qt::blue);
painter->setFont(QFont("Arial", 30));
painter->drawText(rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Text on Image");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to tell the painter where to draw:

```
QImage image("c://image.png");

// tell the painter to draw on the QImage
QPainter* painter = new QPainter(&image); // sorry i forgot the "&"
painter->setPen(Qt::blue);
painter->setFont(QFont("Arial", 30));
// you probably want the to draw the text to the rect of the image
painter->drawText(image.rect(), Qt::AlignCenter, "Text on Image");

QLabel* imageLabel = new QLabel();
imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
imageLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
```

Comment: this doesn't work.  "No matching function for call to QPainter::QPainter(QImage&)"

Comment: Candidates are QPainter::QPainter(QPaintDevice*)... The constructor is expecting a pointer, so you need to give the address of the image to the constructor.

Comment: Is it faster to draw onto image or to overlay a qtextlabel?