# How to insert QImage(or sth like that) into QLabel?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I have both text and image in QLabel, so setPixmap won't satisfy my requirement.
As far as I know, QLabel can load image from file by setting HTML label `<img src="path_to_file" />`. But how can I load image from memory(e.g. QImage)?  Because some images are frequently used, it may have performance problem loading the same image from file every time.

Answer (score 1):

`QLabel` accepts `QPixmaps`, which can be constructed from `QImage`. I do not know about the python interface, but maybe this helps:

In C++ you can set an image like this:

```
QLabel label;
QImage image("path_to_file");
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
label.setPixmap(pixmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices:

1. use two labels, one with the text and one with the image.
2. use a QPainter to draw the text over the image.

Comment: Could you explain more on 2? Do you mean cover the image with text on it? Because there are unknown number of image within the text, so 1 can't help.

Comment: @hbprotoss check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270229/qt-how-to-set-text-on-top-of-qlabel-image

Answer (score 0):

You can also set stylesheet for your QLabel as:-
            QLabel{
                background-image: url(/images/button.png);